# AttributeError with time function

Tags: python, time

I want to sleep my code with random time.
In python, I'm getting the error in the title when I try something like:

```
import random
var=random.randint(50,100)
time.sleep(var)
```

how can I fix it? I've tried to convert the var in float but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: it's `randint`, with a `t`

Comment: Are you sure about the error you get? If I run your code I get this error instead `AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'randin'`. I assume wanted to use `random.choice([50,100])` instead.

Comment: yes it is radint. my bad in copy and paste. I fixed the main post.

Comment: Did you import `time`? And please add the exact and full error message. I doubt that Python just says "AttributeError with time function".

Comment: You have to import the `time` module to use `time.sleep()` from it, just like you had to import `random` in order to use `random.randint()`.

Answer (score 1):

The time module is missing and there is an error in "randin":

```py
import random
import time

var = random.randint(50, 100)
time.sleep(var)
```

Comment: yes I noticed as well but thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. I forgot to add the `import time` in the code.